# MongoDB nested objects

Tags: mongodb

I need help. Recently started teaching mongodb. I can't figure out how to access the nested items. Please help: how can I find the key to "profession"?

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("60a4bbd1753b2bb53e6f7dba"),
"name" : "Bob",
"class" : 7.0,
"lessons" : [ 
    "english", 
    "mathematics"
],
"avgScore" : 3.5,
"parents" : [ 
    {
        "gender" : "female",
        "name" : "Ira"
    }, 
    {
        "gender" : "male",
        "name" : "Dima",
        "profession" : "programmer"
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You Need to use `elemMatch` [ElemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple wasy you can do. You can use `find()` or `aggregation()`.  Here I show you with `find()`

```
db.collection.find({
  parents: {
    $elemMatch: {
      profession: "programmer"
    }
  }
},
{
  "parents.profession.$": 1
})
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/h8v6DBFm9x0)**